# Алгоритм оптимального раскроя материала

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, каким лучше алгоритмом решить задачу такого типа.

Входные данные: параметры прямоугольного листа материала (длина, ширина и количество деталей).
Выходные данные: карта раскроя с наименьшими остатками.

В результате должно получиться что-то подобное:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобные задачи часто встречаются в геймдеве: необходимо множество мелких текстур оптимально упаковать в одну большую. К сожалению, в рунете немного материалов на эту тему.

- [Обзор нескольких алгоритмов на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/160869/)
- [Обсуждение похожей задачи на RSDN](http://rsdn.ru/forum/media/2874639.hot)
- [Перевод статьи Packing Lightmaps на gamedev.ru](http://www.gamedev.ru/pages/coriolis/articles/Packing_Lightmaps) ([оригинал](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html))

В англоязычном сегменте Сети по запросам "packing textures" и "packing lightmaps" находится чуть больше литературы.