# Каким алгоритмом заполнить прямоугольник минимальным количеством квадратов?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Нужно на JS написать функцию заполнения прямоугольника минимальным количеством квадратов.  Прямоугольник может иметь произвольное соотношение сторон.

Прямоугольник и квадраты находятся по абсолютным координатам, так что не важно как будут себя вести сами блоки

Проблема в том что я не могу понять сам принцип реализации. Подскажите алгоритм действий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно попробовать рекурсивный жадный алгоритм, типа вашего заполнения, но у меня нет никакой уверенности в том, что он будет давать оптимальное решение...

Comment: Жадный сработает только для некоторых случаев ([поиграть](http://int-e.eu/~bf3/squares/view.html#13,11)) , но задача кажется слишком серьёзной для уровня "Нужно на JS написать функцию"

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Алгоритм оптимального раскроя материала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/402815/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: Я ранее использовал жадные алгоритмы, но здесь не могу представить как применить.

Comment: Была похожая задача: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/881634/228791

Answer (score 0):

Жадный алгоритм в данном случае выглядит так:

-если ширина равна высоте, то прямоугольник - уже квадрат. break.
-иначе делаем квадрат с размером меньшей стороны, остаётся меньший прямоугольник, с которым работаем дальше аналогично (для `a>b` квадрат `bxb`, остаётся `a-b, b`).

В большинстве случаев это не оптимальный алгоритм.
[Здесь приведён оптимизационный алгоритм](http://int-e.eu/%7Ebf3/squares/), непростой.